# error: cannot convert 'const unsigned char (*)[7]' to 'const unsigned char (*)[]' in initialization

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to build a sort of rudimental database (or rather data storage) structure to store a mapping of different items to specific test cases which is meant to run on an Arduino - so storage space efficiency is a major concern.

So I wrote a couple of typedefs and structs and the header file alone compiles just fine. But as soon as I want to create instances of the structs to actually store the data, I run into several errors which all seem to be very similar to the first one:

```
error: cannot convert 'const uint8_t (*)[7] {aka const unsigned char (*)[7]}' to 'const uint8_t (*)[] {aka const unsigned char (*)[]}' in initialization
```

To reproduce this error, only the following 4 lines are relevant:

-in my header file
(note that the comments tell, what i expect the line to be, not what it is ;) )

```
typedef const uint8_t Testcase[]; //array of const uint8_t

typedef Testcase *Sequence[]; //array of pointer to Testcase (aka array of pointer to array of const uint8_t)
```

-and in my code file:

```
const Testcase ic_1tc_1 = {0x00, 0x10, 0x01, 0x61, 0x00, 0x30, 0x07};

Sequence s1 = {&ic_1tc_1};
```

The Error occurs in the second line of my code file, which I expect to create an array with a single pointer element pointing to the testcase.

All resembling questions i found are about issues with the 'const' keyword, which i sorted out already (i think), so they did not help me.

I understand the compiler error as telling me
"I can't convert an array of length 7 to an array of arbitrary length"
which just does not make sense to me.

Can anyone please explain this to me?

Comment: The error might be better expressed as 'can't convert *a pointer to* an array of length 7 to *a pointer to* an array of arbitrary length' You can't convert pointers to different types to each other (in general). You might be better explaining what you are trying to achieve, than asking questions about these details.

Comment: @Lundin: If by “arrays of incomplete type,” you mean arrays whose elements have incomplete type, that is not the case. The elements of `Testcase` are `const uint8_t`, and the elements of `Sequence` are pointers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If the size is not present, the array type is an incomplete type. 6.7.6.2.

Comment: @Lundin: So by “arrays of incomplete type” you mean the type of the array is incomplete, not the type that the array is an array of is incomplete? Then your phrasing is unclear. What then does it mean to have “arrays of incomplete type, with an unknown type”? If `Testcase` is an array of incomplete type because the array size is not known, what is the “unknown type”? The other type in the definition of `Testcase`, its element type, is `const uint8_t`, so it is known.

Comment: Furthermore, it is possible to use arrays of unknown size in C (using them is different from defining them), and it is possible to use pointers to arrays of unknown size. And it is rude and inappropriate to make comments like “It would seem that you don't understand how to use arrays in C and that's that...” Even were it true, lacking knowledge is certainly not an unchangeable state, so it is false that “that’s that”. You should stop criticizing people for the state of their knowledge.

Comment: You should ask about C and C++ separately. The rules are different for the different languages. The code shown compiles as C in Clang and not as C++ in Clang (Apple LLVM 10.0.0 with clang=1000.11.45.5).

Comment: @EricPostpischil If you don't understand what incomplete array type means, then maybe ask a question here on SO. I'm not going to teach it to you over comments. Now kindly stop stalking me.

Comment: @Lundin that means the size is a property of the type rather than the object so it is impossible to tell the compiler that all objects of type Testcase are arrays of uint8_t but vary in size/length...
I understand that the Testcase type does not tell the size, so i do understand that i can't create an array of Testcases - but why does this prevent me from creating an array of pointers(which are a 'complete' type) to objects of type Testcase

Comment: @john Why is the length of an array a property of the pointer to that array or the array type respectively?
I explained the context in the first paragraph and i think it is rather obvious that a `Testcase` is an array of numbers defining my test conditions and a `Sequence` is a list of Testcases

Comment: @Sorontik `typedef Testcase *Sequence[];` creates an incomplete array of _array pointers_ to an array of uint8_t with incomplete type. Your typedefs makes the code very hard to read. There's two very sound rules: never hide pointers behind typedefs and never hide arrays behind typedefs.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: `Why is the length of an array a property of the pointer to that array?` Because (among other reasons probably) if it wasn't, then it would not be possible to use pointer arithmetic to get the next array sibling (in a multidimensional array). `or the array type respectively` If the length of the array wasn't property of the array type, then there could not be multidimensional arrays at all.

Comment: @eerorika considering multidimensional arrays, all but the outermost array size has to be known - but as far as i see (and definitely as far as i intended) I only use one-dimensional arrays of types with well-known sizes (uint8_t and pointers)

Comment: @Sorontik You use a static (or automatic) array. The outermost array size may be determined at runtime only for dynamically allocated arrays. It must be compile time constant for static and automatic arrays. Regardless, we were discussing pointers. A pointer to an array which is within a multidimensional array and a pointer to an array that is not within a multidimensional array are the same pointer type and have the same limitations. The size must be known.

Comment: @Lundin My Problem is: I want to store a number Sequences which consist of different numbers of Testcases. Each Testcase consists of a differing number of bytes.
I know the length of each testcase and sequence because i store them in a dedicated variable or can calculate them from other sources.
Also the complete list/tree/structure is static and fully known/defined at compile-time.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, I would guess that you actually want something like a const array of structs, each struct containing size + a pointer to data, each data being a const uint8_t array of any size. `typedef struct { size_t size; const uint8_t* data; } test_case_t;`

Comment: @Lundin I'd rename data to testcase and call the struct sequence_t but yeah, thats it. Yet i find it rather irritating when a pointer has a different type than the data... In your case one must know that even though data is of type uint8_t* it actually points to a whole array of uint8_t. If it was `uint8_t* data[]` it would be obvious. This is probably due to the fact that I'm coming from higher level languages and am used to having the type tell me what a variable _is_ and the name what it is used _for_, both in a meaningful and not technical way.

Comment: @Sorontik That's why you'd wrap it up in an ADT that accesses the data and the caller won't have to worry about the internals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

Replace

```
Sequence s1 = {&ic_1tc_1};
```

with

```
const uint8_t *s1[] = {ic_1tc_1};
```

---

**Explanation:**

Let's start with simple things.

When you omit the array size in a definition, the size is deduced:

```
int x[] = {1,2,3};
```

Here, the type of `x` is `int[3]`.

Note that the type is not `int[]`. Types representing arrays of unknown bound are *incomplete types*, and no objects of such types can be created.

Above works even with `typedef`s:

```
typedef int array[];
array x = {1,2,3};
```

Note that the type of `x` is not `array`, since it's `int[3]` rather than `int[]`.

---

Even though objects of incomplete types can't be created, you can create *pointers* to such types.

For example:

```
int (*ptr)[];
```

This declaration has the same effect as:

```
typedef int array[];
array *ptr;
```

The only thing this pointer could point to is `int[]`, but since objects of such type can't be created, pointers to arrays of unknown bound aren't used often.

<sup>(Although I can imagine some peculiar use cases. You could *declare* an array to have an unknown bound and specify a size when defining it elsewhere. You could then form a pointer to the array using the declaration, and the type of such pointer will be `T(*)[]`.)</sup>

You can't assign an address of `int[N]` to such a pointer, since formally `int[]` and `int[N]` are different types.

```
typedef int array[];
array x = {1,2,3};
array *ptr = &x; // Error, can't convert `int(*)[3]` to `int(*)[]`.
```

This is exactly what you're trying to do in your code.

One possible solution is to use the correct type for the pointer:

```
typedef int array[];
array x = {1,2,3};
int (*ptr)[3] = &x;
```

But since you said you need to have an array of pointers to arrays of various sizes, that is not an option.

Another possible solution is to cast the pointer, but that doesn't look convenient (and I'm not 100% sure using the resulting pointer is well-defined).

You probably should just store pointers to first elements of your arrays:

```
typedef int array[];
array x = {1,2,3};
int *ptr = x;
```

In your code it would look like so:

```
const Testcase ic_1tc_1 = {0x00, 0x10, 0x01, 0x61, 0x00, 0x30, 0x07};
const uint8_t *s1[] = {ic_1tc_1};
```

Comment: Re “from the point of view of the language, `int[]` and `int[N]` are different unrelated types”: “The language” is ambiguous; the question is tagged both C and C++. In C, the types are not unrelated; they are compatible.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'll think of a better wording. :) *"they are compatible."* Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: C 6.7.6.2 6 says array types are compatible if they have compatible element types and do not have different constant lengths. Thus, if one or both arrays have unspecified length or variable length, the types are compatible. (That means C allows you to do some bad things like assign a pointer to a variable-length array of length 7 to a pointer to a variable-length array of length 4.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks for the answer, i'll try that.
With your explanation I don't understand why line 1, the testcase definition, works?
Testcase is `uint8_t[]` but the value is `uint8_t[7]`
Furthermore i can create another object of type Testcase with different length and it compiles fine (which should be wrong if the compiler derived the length of the array in Testcase to `uint8_t[7]' from the first testcase definition - then at least the second testcase definition with e.g. 3 elements should raise an error)

Comment: @Sorontik What is *"line 1, the testcase definition"*? I assume it's `const Testcase ic_1tc_1 = {...};`? *"Testcase is `uint8_t[]` but the value is `uint8_t[7]`"* The size of the array was not specified, so the compiler determined the size based on the number of the initializers. It's similar to `typedef int array[]; array x = {1,2,3};`. *"i can create another object of type Testcase with different length and it compiles fine"* The determined array size is not associated with the `typedef` in any way. For each object of type `Testcase`, the compiler determines the array size independently.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you're right, i was refering to that
that means the array length is _not_ part of the type so why is it causing problems?

Comment: @Sorontik I thought the answer explains that, no? `&ic_1tc_1` has type `T(*)[N]` (more specifically, `const unsigned char (*)[7]`), and the type of elements of your array is `T(*)[]` (more specifically, `const unsigned char (*)[]`). The compiler considers those to be pointers to different types, which can't be freely converted to each other.

Comment: but u just said that the compiler determines the array size of each object of type `testcase` independently so it can vary and is not part of type `testcase`?

Comment: @Sorontik I don't see a contradiction here. Look again at this example: `typedef int array[]; array x = {1,2,3}; array *ptr = &x;` (which doesn't compile), and make sure you understand why it doesn't compile.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat **either** the size of objects of type testcase is part of the type - then all objects of type testcase must have the same size and definitions with other sizes were impossible, **or** the size is not part of the type - then it can not cause trouble
The alternative is a contradiction in itself: it would mean I can have two variables, both of type `testcase` which are not of the same type. Thats like stating `x=2` and `y=2` but `x!=y` -> impossible

Comment: @Sorontik The size is not a part of the `Testcase` type. You need to understand that the type of `const Testcase ic_1tc_1 = {...};` is NOT `const Testcase`. A simplified example is included in the answer: in `typedef int array[];
array x = {1,2,3};`, the type of `x` is not `array`.

Comment: Ahh, i see... A Variable declared to be of a certain type actually is not neccessarily of that type... _well done C_... - But thank you @HolyBlackCat for your explanations and patience, i think i got that now :D